# matlab. copy values from one matrix based on values of another matrix

Tags: matlab

I have matrix a <500 x 500> and matrix b <500 x 2>.
Matrix b contains two types of values which are row and column coordinates for matrix a. I would like to use the values in matrix b to to copy all the values that fall on the row and column coordinates of matrix a.

see example below

```
matrix a          matrix b   output
1  2  3  4  5     1 5        1   2   3  4  5
6  7  8  9  10    2 5        7   8   9  10
11 12 13 14 15    1 3        11  12  13
```

Comment: What are the values of b supposed to be exactly? And what do you mean by "the values that fall on the row and column coordinates of matrix a"? You're being kind of vague in your wording.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because every row will have a different length you'll need to save the values into a cell array.

Something like this should work:

```
output = cell( size(b,1),1);

for i = 1:size(a,1)

  output{i} = a(i, b(i,1):b(i,2) )

end
```

Comment: How do I get around with nonintegers? The code hangs when it runs into nonintegers. Also, I cannot modify the data to make a noninteger into an integer. I have to maintain the data as is, be it integer or noninteger. Thanks so much.